# Can you load a table view from plist with dynamic and static sections?

Tags: uitableview, dynamic, swift3, tableview, plist

I am loading my table views data from a plist file, using index path.
I used that tutorial as base https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

But I did some modifications, my plist format now is as follows :

```
root : dictionary
    viewController : Array
        headerIDS : Array
        cellIDS : Array
        container : Array
            index 0 : Array (Section)
                index 0 : dictionary (cell info)
                index 1 : dictionary (cell info)
```

Which is working fine, but I want some sections to don't be index path dependent.

I want 1 section for example to have 1 type of cell and the number of cells to be dynamic from an online fetched array.

Now I am getting the cell by passing the index path to my model and gives me back the correct cell of the correct section and row.

Any suggestions how I could modify my structure in order to do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer I was looking for.

The answer is to create a uitableviewcell that has a table view inside.

So the main table view structure of the plist will remain the same and I will have a dynamic cell with the information that I need